# It's possible to draw multiple and different textures in openGL for iPhone with a single draw call?

Tags: iphone, opengl

I have this game with some variety of textures. Whenever I draw a texture I bind It and draw It.

It's possible to draw all the elements of my game in just one draw call ? , with Interleaved Arrays ...how can I do It ?

The performance of my game will increase by doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you would benefit from using a [texture atlas](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW2), one giant texture containing all of your smaller ones.  For OpenGL ES on the iPhone, [Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2230.html#TNTAG10) that you place all of the vertices that you can draw at one time in a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO), and that you interleave the vertex, normal, color, and texture information within that buffer (in that order).  Note that the VBO itself doesn't give you a significant performance boost over a standard array on the original iPhones, but the 3GS has hardware VBO support.

Either by grouping data into a VBO or an array, I've seen significant performance improvements in my application when I reduced the number of draw calls.

Another area that you might want to look at is in reducing the size of your geometry.  By going from a GLfloat to GLshort for my vertex and normal coordinate data, I saw an over 30% improvement in OpenGL ES rendering speed on the iPhone 3G.

Comment: In addition, it might be worth checking out this presentation by ngmoco: Overview of iPhone OpenGL optimization techniques - http://gamemakers.ngmoco.com/post/111712416/stanford-university-and-apple-were-kind-enough-to

Comment: Agreed. That's an excellent presentation when it comes to tuning OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 1):

TBH you are better off doing it with seperate draw calls.  Performance is unlikely to be noticeably affected.

There "may" be ways to do it by indexing into slices of a volume texture (or texture array) but you'd need the 3GS to do this and it wouldn't work on the old iPhone.  I also doubt you'd get any noticeable performance improvement by doing it.

Comment: oh, haha, internet slang fail on my part ;-)